# How to use TimerOne while calculating time?

Tags: arduino-mega, c++, timers, buzzer

I'm trying to get warning with buzzer while I get same values on 3 seconds. But first warning doesn't wait 3 seconds. Second warning is correct. Code is attached. BlinkLED1() method is same BlinkLED2. Probably, I'm missing crowning touch. Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

```
void initialsettings(double roll,double pitch){
  if(level==0){
    if(roll>=34 && timerstatus==false){

        Timer1.initialize(3000000);
        timerstatus=true;
        Timer1.attachInterrupt(blinkLED);
    } else{
         Timer1.stop();
         timerstatus=false;
         level=0;
    }

   }else if(level==1){
      if(roll<=-34 && timerstatus==false){

        Timer1.initialize(3000000);
        timerstatus=true;
         Timer1.attachInterrupt(blinkLED2);
      } else{
           Timer1.stop();
         timerstatus=false;

      }

  }else if(level==2){


  }
}

void blinkLED(void)
{
    noInterrupts();
    Timer1.stop();

    //Timer1.restart();
    digitalWrite(buzzerpin,HIGH);
    delay(7000);
    digitalWrite(buzzerpin,LOW);
    timerstatus=false;
    interrupts();
    if(level==0){
      level=1;
      Serial.println("level 1");
    }
  Serial.println("Sag ");
    //Serial.print("\n");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Timer1.attachInterrupt(blinkLED);
```

...

```
void blinkLED(void)
{
    noInterrupts();
    Timer1.stop();

    //Timer1.restart();
    digitalWrite(buzzerpin,HIGH);
    delay(7000);
    digitalWrite(buzzerpin,LOW);
    timerstatus=false;
    interrupts();
    if(level==0){
      level=1;
      Serial.println("level 1");
    }
  Serial.println("Sag ");
```

---

- Don't do serial prints inside an interrupt service routine (ISR).
- Don't use `delay()` inside an ISR.
- Don't turn interrupts on or off inside an ISR.
- Variables shared between an ISR and the main code should be `volatile` (I can't see from your [snippet](http://snippets-r-us.com/) whether they are or not).

Reference: [Interrupts](http://www.gammon.com.au/interrupts)